# Laravel not wanting to redirect to the right page

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

Currently, I'm trying to get all the info from my database and make the function redirect to a list page where all the data gets displayed. The redirect is currently not working and I'm getting the following error:

Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct(): Argument #2 ($status) must be of type int, array given.

The error is specifically coming from the return redirect part of my code. This is working fine for my classmates who link it to the same blade.php page as I am. Do I need to add anything else just because I am redirecting instead of using the view declaration type?

My controller:

```
    public function show(): RedirectResponse
    {
        $projects = project::all();

        return redirect('list', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }
```

page it needs to link to (just for reference):

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('content')
    <main>
        @foreach($project as $projects)
            <h2>{{ $project->title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ $project->picture_url }}</p>
            <p>{{ $project->description }}</p>
            <p>{{ $project->explanation }}</p>
            <button> Edit </button>
            <button> Delete </button>
        @endforeach
    </main>
@endsection
```

Comment: I think you want `return redirect()->route('list', ['projects' => $projects]);`here, https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes

Comment: Also note that the function definition for redirect is `function redirect($to = null, $status = 302, $headers = [], $secure = null)`, so the second parameter is the status.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return redirect()->route('routename', compact('projects'));
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a named route you will need to use the `Redirector` instance which you can get by calling the redirect method without any parameters.

This instance allows you to call a `route` method which will return a `RedirectResponse` to target named routes, like this:

```php
return redirect()->route('route-name');
```

You can pass parameters in the second argument of this function, so in your case you would need something like this:

```php
public function show(): RedirectResponse
{
    $projects = project::all();

    return redirect()->route('list', ['projects' => $projects]);
}
```

Since these kind of redirect responses are common, Laravel also provides a `to_route` helper, which can be used like this:

```php
public function show(): RedirectResponse
{
    $projects = project::all();

    return to_route('list', ['projects' => $projects]);
}
```

See the laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes